# how to solve a problem about a specific compiler

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int x = 50;
     cout << 70;
     return 0;
}
```

And the error is like this:

```
undefined reference to `WinMain' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And my compiler is `minWG`, and I'm sure that I've installed it correctly.

Comment: I think this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/16946307/10035556

Comment: Are you getting a linkage error?

Comment: Please show how you are invoking your compiler.  You compiler believes it's compiling for Windows OS.  The starting point for Windows OS applications is `WinMain`.

Comment: You need to build for the console subsystem, not the Windows subsystem. Usually that is the default. You may have `-mwindows` on your compile line overriding that.

Comment: solved. I just needed to save the program before compiling it!